# Alfresco Office Addin Source

Tags: alfresco

Is the source available for the Alfresco MS Office plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's right there in SVN. Have a look in projects/extensions/AlfrescoOffice2003 for the C# client-side code (it wraps MSIE and interfaces with Office).

The webscripts are in: projects/remote-api/config/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/office

And finally the client-side web assets are in: projects/web-client/source/web/scripts/office

You'll need the Visual Studio Tools for Office installed (search for "VSTO") and if prompted for a password, it's "alfresco".

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Arrgh Thank you - it seems obvious once you know where to look!

Answer (score 3):

The code for the Office addin now officially lives at http://code.google.com/p/alfresco-ms-office-plugin/

Answer (score 2):

Just a head's up that we're in the process of donating the Office Add-ins to the community, so the source code will be moving somewhere public (probably Google Code) in the coming weeks/months.

If you're interested in becoming a maintainer / committer to that project, please let me know!